# Bootstrap Dropdowns: How to trigger on hover, but only when one is already open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation

I'd like to emulate the behaviour of a classic main menu in Windows. The process-flow is this:

1. Click on a menu item, such as 'File' - menu opens
2. Move pointer to another menu item, such as 'Edit' - menu opens, 'File' menu closes.

I have a normal `navbar`, with only dropdown menus.

How can I emulate this behaviour in Bootstrap 3? I know I'd need to override the `click` and `hover` events, but am not sure exactly how to go about this.

**Edit:** I have seen [this](https://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/), but it doesn't appear to work, and seems to be hover only. (At least, the demo doesn't work, which isn't very encouraging.)

**Edit:** My terrible attempt so far:

```
$(function() {
    $("li.dropdown").hover(
        function() {
            if ($('.open').length !== 0) {
                $('.open').removeClass('.open');
                $(this).addClass('open');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

It does check first to see if one is already open, but when I close all menus (at this stage, they all remain open - fixing that now) and do it again, it doesn't follow the same process. I'm sure there's something highly obvious I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think I've seen such a thing before. You'll probably have to write some jQuery. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm busy messing with some ideas now, but it seems to be breaking... Will update my question with a terrible attempt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. My logic was half-off today. Also not used to Bootstrap and how things operate.

This works like a charm - just checking to see that it is full-proof:

```
$(function() {
    $("li.dropdown").hover(
        function() {
            if ($('.open').length !== 0) {
                $('.open').removeClass('open').find('>ul').css('display', 'none');
                $(this).addClass('open').find('>ul').css('display', 'inline-block');
            }
        }
    );
});
```